# Cross-classloader class loading

Tags: java, reflection, classloader, urlclassloader

I have a `CustomClassLoader` that loads classes from a `Map<String, byte[]>`. The classes that I am loading depend on other, unloaded classes. I have the jar files that contain said classes in a `UrlClassLoader` that is initiated before the `CustomClassLoader`, but when the `CustomClassLoader` tried to load a class that has an external import (a jarfile in the UrlClassLoader) an exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: external/class/in/urlclassloader/ClassImportedByLoadedClass
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at CustomClassLoader.defineClass(EncryptedByteArrayClassLoader.java:35)
```

I need some way to either:

a) load all the classes that are in the `URLClassLoader`

or

b) have some way to set the URLClassLoader as the default ClassLoader for the classes that are being loaded from memory (instead of my CustomClassLoader)

Line 35:

```
public Class<?> defineClass(String name, byte[] bytes) {
    return super.defineClass(name, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
}
```

I have tried setting the context ClassLoader like:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(jarLoader);
```

where jarLoader is the `URLClassLoader`.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override [`ClassLoader(ClassLoader parent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#ClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29) constructor in your `CustomClassLoader` and pass your `URLClassLoader` there:

```
class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
     public CustomClassLoader(URLClassLoader parent, ...your data...) {
         super(parent);
         ...
     }
}

CustomClassLoader customClassLoader = new CustomClassLoader(jarLoader, ...);
```